# numpy index from k-th last element to k-th first element

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

l would like to explore my array from k-th last element to k-th first element.

```
my_list=[3,4,5,8,18,45,98,28,1,17,58]

my_sub_list=[17,58,3,4]
```

**my_sub_list** contains the two last elements and the two first elements.

**What is my target ?**

looking for a way to to access elements from the last to first .

Is there any way to do the following  ?

```
 my_sublist[-4:2]
```

In general case : `my_sublist[k-last:k-first]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on `my_sub_list` a little bit more by telling us which is which? Also, pls add your expected output and explain why `my_sublist[-4:2]` doesn't work for you?

Comment: You should just concatenate the two portions. If you are using Python lists: `my_sub_list = my_list[-4:] + my_list[:2]`. With NumPy arrays: `my_sub_array = np.concatenate([my_array[-4:], my_array[:2]])`.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd, my_list[-4:2] returns [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you just want to look at the k-first and k-last elements, so you could do:

```
my_sub_list = my_list[-k_last:] + my_list[:k_first]
```

If you need this often, just put it into a function:

```
def last_to_first(l, k_last, k_first):
    return l[-k_last:] + l[:k_first]
```

Comment: Great point. Just copied it from the initial question. Fixed it.

Comment: great answer. Thank you